# What database schema should I use?

Tags: sql, database-schema

I need help designing a SQL table.  Suppose I have **cardnumber**, **cardtype**, field1, field2, and field3.

**Cardtype** is an enumeration that can be "front", "back", or "both".

1. I want to SELECT front.field1, front.field2, front.field3, back.field1, back.field2, back.field3 FROM some table or view WHERE **cardnumber**=XXX.
2. Most of the records will just contain field1, field2, field3, and "both" indicating that I should get front.field1 to be the same as back.field1, etc... when I SELECT.  When "front" and "back" are different, I will need two rows with the same cardnumber, but one with "front" and the other with "back", along with the appropriate field1...field3 for each side.

How do I design this table.  Should I be using some VIEW of an INNER JOIN or a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN of some sort?

I'm open to different designs but I am hoping that any design will be easy to maintain (taking into account that most records will be one row containing "both") and can satisfy my SELECT requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Card
--------------------------------------------
CardNumber     CardType_id    field1     etc

CardType
--------------------------------------------
ID     Description


SELECT
     Card.*,
     CardType.Description
FROM Card
          INNER JOIN CardType
                ON Card.CardType_id = CardType.ID
WHERE CardType.Description = 'your description value'
```

Comment: OK - this almost gave me what I was looking for - I ended up with all 4 permutations: FRONT/FRONT, FRONT/BACK, BACK/FRONT, and BACK/BACK, but this can be easily corrected by adding filters to the WHERE statement to return just 1 of the 4.  tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you already have a design in mind and are looking for a query. I added the create table/insert statements to show my interpretation of the question. This assumes a number of integrity items such as:

- if you have a 'FRONT' record for a card, you will also have one (and
  only one) 'BACK' record for a card. i
- if you have a 'BOTH' record for a card, there will be no other record

Ran this using Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE card(cardnumber int, cardtype varchar(5), field1 varchar(16), field2 varchar(16), field3 varchar(16));

INSERT INTO card VALUES(1, 'FRONT', 'a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO card VALUES(1, 'BACK',  'd', 'e', 'f');
INSERT INTO card VALUES(2, 'BOTH',  'x', 'y', 'z');


SELECT c1.cardnumber
      ,c1.field1 AS frontField1, c1.field2 AS frontField2, c1.field3 AS frontField3
      ,c2.field1 AS backField1, c2.field2 AS backField2, c2.field3 AS backField3
  FROM card c1
      ,card c2
  WHERE c1.cardtype = 'FRONT'
    AND c2.cardtype = 'BACK'
    AND c1.cardnumber = c2.cardnumber
UNION
SELECT c.cardnumber
      ,c.field1 AS frontField1, c.field2 AS frontField2, c.field3 AS frontField3
      ,c.field1 AS backField1, c.field2 AS backField2, c.field3 AS backField3
  FROM card c
  WHERE c.cardtype = 'BOTH';

 cardnumber | frontfield1 | frontfield2 | frontfield3 | backfield1 | backfield2 | backfield3
------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------
          1 | a           | b           | c           | d          | e          | f
          2 | x           | y           | z           | x          | y          | z
```

Comment: ah - yes: union works great as well.  ty for your suggestion.